# Tkinter automatically update Label after Entry in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I made an tkinter window for some kind of calculation from the data entered. I simplified my code below to illustrate my question. Currently, the result will show up once I click search. However, I want the result to show up automatically once text are entered in the entry box without the "search" button. I tried "after" using window.after(100, self.searchbarcode) but it did not work for me. Appreciate your inputs. Thank you!

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk

import os.path


import numpy as np


class searchloc:
    def __init__(self):
        window=tk.Tk()
        window.geometry("800x300")
        window.title("Search Location")
        Label(window, text="Scan",font="Helvetica 24").grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
        self.barcode=StringVar()
        self.outcomes=StringVar()
        self.text1=tk.Entry(window,textvariable=self.barcode,font="Helvetica 36")
        self.text1.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=(0,5))
        Label(window,textvariable=self.outcomes,font="Helvetica 68 bold").grid(row=7,column=2,sticky=E)
        wsheet1 = gsheet.worksheet("Sheet2")
        mydata1 = wsheet1.get_values()
        mydata2=mydata1[1:]
        cool=mydata1[0]
        look = pd.DataFrame(mydata2, dtype=str)
        #window.after(1, self.searchbarcode())
        #self.text1.bind('<Enter>', self.searchbarcode())
        Button(window,text='search',command=self.searchbarcode,font="Helvetica 38").grid(row=5,column=2,padx=(100,5),pady=5,sticky=W)
        #Button(window,text='clear',command=self.clear_text,font="Helvetica 38").grid(row=5,column=2,padx=(100,5),pady=5,sticky=E)
        window.mainloop()

    #def clear_text(self):
        
        
    def searchbarcode(self):
        bar = self.barcode.get()
        outtt=bar[1:5]
        self.outcomes.set(outtt)
        self.text1.delete(0, 'end')
        


searchloc()
```

Comment: If it doesn't wait for a button click, how should it determine when to do the calculation? When you've stopped typing? After each character? When you press the return key?

Comment: after pressing the return key would be fine. but it seems I couldn't not bind entry key correctly. I'm using a barcode scanner as input device, so there is no typing. Every scan will result in a full barcode. And currently, I have set it up that once I click "search", it will show search result, and then clear the text in the entry box for my next scan.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to happen when you press the return key, you almost had it right. The function has to accept an `event` parameter even if you don't use it, and you need to make sure you pass the function itself, not the result of calling the function (ie: `self.searchbarcode` instead of `self.searchbarcode()`).

Also, the event is `<Return>`. `<Enter>` is for when the mouse enters the widget.

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.text1.bind('<Return>', self.searchbarcode)
    ...

def searchbarcode(self, event):
    ...
```

If you want to call `searchbarcode` both with or without the event parameter, give it a default value of `None`:

```
def searchbarcode(self, event=None):
    ...
```

Comment: I have another question..If I modify the code to bind "enter" with the function, it seems the result show up slower than what I had before (using the "search" button). Is it really something, or was it just something wrong with my computer..?

Comment: @user6840557: I've updated my answer. I forgot to notice you used `<Enter>`. That doesn't represent the enter key, it represents the mouse entering the widget.